# Saving current property of PageTitle textblock and items of listbox

Tags: c#, .net, windows-phone-7

I just started playing with WP7, and i have probably easy problem.
In my app im navigating through pages and simultaneously sending strings.
And to the source of problem. Im on this page:

```
namespace Zakupy
{
    public partial class List : PhoneApplicationPage
    {


        public List()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

        }



        protected override void OnNavigatedTo(System.Windows.Navigation.NavigationEventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnNavigatedTo(e);


            string msg = "";
            string lister = "";
            string sklad = "";


              if (NavigationContext.QueryString.TryGetValue("msg", out msg))
                {
                    string name = "";
                    name = msg;
                    PageTitle.Text = name;
                }

            if (NavigationContext.QueryString.TryGetValue("add", out lister))
            {
                sklad = lister;
                listBox1.Items.Add(sklad);
            }

        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/AddList.xaml", UriKind.Relative));
        }


    }
}
```

Navigated from another page. From that page I'm sending pagetitle and i set it. And its working fine to this point.
Next im navigating to next page where im adding items to listbox. On navigating back to page above i have 2 problems:
 1. page title is reseting.
 2. Previous item in listbox is replaced with one that is currently sended>
I'm probably missing something really easy, but help appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I misunderstood. Each time you navigate to a page creates a new instance of the page (try to put a breakpoint in your constructor).

If you want to save data across your pages, you can store data in app.cs file. This created only once and is available from all your pages throughout the app's live time.

In your App.cs file

```
 public partial class App: Application
 {
     public List <string> myList = new List <string> ();
     ...
```

In your OnNavigationTo handler (only show for handling a list)

```
    protected override void OnNavigatedTo(System.Windows.Navigation.NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.NavigationMode != System.Windows.Navigation.NavigationMode.Back)
        {

            if (NavigationContext.QueryString.TryGetValue("add", out lister))
            {
                sklad = lister;
                ((App)Application.Current).myList.Add(sklad);
            }

            listBox1.ItemSource = ((App)Application.Current).myList;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

OnNavigatedTo is allways called when your application navigates to it, eather from the NavigationService or when you hit the "Back" button.

Have you try to test if your are navigating back an see what your QueryString contains, maybe this holds data you not want to show. You can allwas test if you are navigating back in the NavigationEventArgs e's properties.

```
    protected override void OnNavigatedTo(System.Windows.Navigation.NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnNavigatedTo(e);
        if (e.NavigationMode == System.Windows.Navigation.NavigationMode.Back)
        ...
    }
```

Comment: I'm fully aware of it, but thats not the point. My problem is that after navigating to page with code listed above that page is reseting and the only change on it is the current "thing" sended through value of query string or nothing. And QueryString are filtered with type of message sended in uri. I want to save elements on this bage for the whole time when app is active.